# Import issue with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, import, workbench

I am trying to import a .csv (or .txt it doesn't matter) with MySQL Workbench and I am actually using the following command :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/csv/file/model.csv' INTO TABLE test.dummy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

My .csv file is placed in the mysql/data folder of the server where my database is placed (on localhost). MySQL Workbench tells me "Query interrupted".
I previously tried to put the full path but the query was running successfully without results. My database was still empty...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: /path/to/your/csv/file/ is this the path to your csv file?

Comment: Don't put non-mysql-managed files in your mysql/data folder! Can you run this `LOAD DATA ...` command from a command-line client instead of the workbench? It may give you a better error message.  Is the protection of your csv file set up so your mysqld server can read it?

Comment: The protection of my csv file? I don't know what you mean by that... If you mean the read and write protection, you have to know that my file have been extracted by Access which didn't asked me to define a protection.

Comment: Also maybe I could ask my question in a different way : "Where am I supposed to put this csv file and how am I supposed to declare the path to it (because the direct path doesn't work)?" I hope you'll get my purpose more precisely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so... Problem solved. It just seems that MySQLWorbench accepts this request with a direct path (no errors, script executed) but doesn't refresh his table view... So my table have been fullfilled around 3 times before I restarted MySQLWorkbench to discover that my table was full.

So... Problem solved. Sorry for the time loss.